# Codeigniter in subdirectory - why does resolving controller/class/function not work?

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing

I have a base codeigniter setup and can not get it to run. I thought I had understood that it works like the following:

```
http://localhost/index.php/class/function
```

where `class` points to the controller.

The problem I have is that my install is in a subfolder like so:

```
http://localhost/path%20to%20ci/index.php/class/function
```

and CI always gives me a 404 even the controller class exists.

I've digged into the CI source and it shows me that the whole request URI is taken as input:

```
path to ci/index.php/class/function
```

Is there anything I need to configure to make CI detect the prefix automatically for  resolving `class` and `function`?

Can I or even do I need to setup a base path?

**Concrete Example**

My CI path is accessible via:

```
http://localhost/workspace/Limesurvey%20CI/index.php
```

The working controller is:

```
http://localhost/workspace/Limesurvey%20CI/index.php/installer
```

Setting the base path in `application/config/config.php` to:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/workspace/Limesurvey%20CI/';
```

which is according to the documentation given for that setting.

Comment: Looks like  your base URL is correct. Do you have an `.htaccess` file setup? Have you made any additional configuration changes to the base CI install? Are you sure that you're creating a controller class properly?

Comment: There is no `.htaccess` in action, and the base CI install is merely unchanged. The only change I did was the `base_url` configuration. I once had set `$application_folder` and `$system_path` to a full qualified pathname in `index.php` but reverted those changes and it does not make a difference. The controller is by the Limesurvey application, it should work, I will review it now in more detail.

Comment: Okay I was trying again for the fatal error I commented below, it looks like that the installer controller is loading the config again, this might be a bug in the CI application as well which is hindering me to find out more. I'll keep digging. Thanks for your detailed feedback so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One can not expect that Codeigniter does RFC conform URL processing. Instead to solve the issue, one must know that Codeigniter can not work with all URLs, in this case, it's not possible to have a space character `%20` within the base url.

Moving the installation to another path that does not have the space character solved the issue:

```
http://localhost/workspace/Limesurvey_CI/index.php/installer
```

Additionally, changing the `$config['base_url']` in `application/config/config.php` is not needed. It can stay with it's default value `''` (empty string).

Answer (score 0):

You define the `base_url` within `application/config/config.php` by setting the config variable `$config['base_url']`.

Once configured it should resolve your issue.

Comment: I'm [trying to do so](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Dynamic_Base_Url/), but this triggers the `config.php` to be loaded twice, which causes a fatal error because it re-defines the `__autoload` function. Will try for a more static approach.

Comment: I've added my concrete URLs and the new configuration setting. With that setting config.php does not get loaded twice, but I still get the 404 errors. You have an idea?

Comment: Do you need to have a dynamic base URL? Have you made any additional config changes...or changed the `routes.php` file at all?

Comment: For the moment I don't need it. Replaced it with a static one, see as well my updated question where I put concrete values in.

Comment: It looks like that the CI `Router` and `Uri` are not reflecting the `$config['base_url']` setting at all. I did a search within CI core and it looks like that it is used in output only.